# How can I set and clear the RTS line of a serial port. C++ POSIX

Tags: c++, ubuntu, serial-port, posix

I want to control the RTS line on the serial port to wake up a device. Here is some rough test code to open the serial port. I need to set the RTS line low for 500ms. I'm having trouble googleing/understanding how to control the lines. Any Hints?

EDIT: OR controlling the CTS/DTR, any other line besides the Tx/Rx lines to connect to a pin of the robot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>   /* Standard types */
#include <fcntl.h>    /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>    /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h>  /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <getopt.h>



using namespace std;

int fd_global;
FILE* fp_global;
int serialport_init(const char* serialport, int baud);
int serialport_read_until(int fd);
int fpeek(FILE* stream);
bool fexists(const char *filename);


void* screen_thread(void* arg) {
    while(1) {
    }
}



int main(void) {

    pthread_t screen_thread_id;
    int flags;
    int baudrate = B9600;  // default
    fd_global = serialport_init((char*)"/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate);
    if(fd_global==-1) {
        cout << "Open port: error\n";
        return -1;
    }

    fp_global = fdopen(fd_global, "r");


    if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd_global, F_GETFL, 0))) flags = 0;
    fcntl(fd_global, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    //pthread_create(&screen_thread_id, NULL, screen_thread, (void*)NULL);    

    serialport_read_until(fd_global);
    return 0;
}

int serialport_read_until(int fd)
{
    char b[1];
    while(1) { 
        int n = read(fd, b, 1);  //Read byte at a time
        if(n==-1) { 
            printf("N");fflush(stdout);
            perror("READ: ");
         }
        else if( n==0 ) {
            printf("Z");fflush(stdout);
        } else if(n>0) {

            printf(":%d:",n);fflush(stdout);


        }
        usleep(100*1000);

            if (fexists("/dev/ttyUSB0")) 
                printf("CONNECTED\n");
            else
                printf("NOT CONNECTED\n");

    }
    return 0;
}

bool fexists(const char *filename)
{
  ifstream ifile(filename);
  return ifile;
}



int serialport_init(const char* serialport, int baud)
{
    struct termios toptions;
    int fd;

    // Open port
    fd = open(serialport, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1)  {
        perror("init_serialport: Unable to open port ");
        return -1;
    }

    // Read current termios settings
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &toptions) < 0) {
        perror("init_serialport: Couldn't get term attributes");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set baud rate variable
    speed_t brate = baud;
    switch(baud) {
    case 2400:   brate=B2400;   break;
    case 4800:   brate=B4800;   break;
    case 9600:   brate=B9600;   break;
#ifdef B14400
    case 14400:  brate=B14400;  break;
#endif
    case 19200:  brate=B19200;  break;
#ifdef B28800
    case 28800:  brate=B28800;  break;
#endif
    case 38400:  brate=B38400;  break;
    case 57600:  brate=B57600;  break;
    case 115200: brate=B115200; break;
    }
    cfsetispeed(&toptions, brate);
    cfsetospeed(&toptions, brate);

    // Setup termios for 8N1
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;

    // Reccomended settings
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;   // no flow control
    toptions.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;  // turn on read & ignore ctrl lines
    toptions.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // turn off s/w flow ctrl
    toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
    toptions.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // make raw

    // Setting when read() releases
    // see: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html (Still a little confusing)
    toptions.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
    toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 20;

    // Apply settings
    if( tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions) < 0) {
        perror("init_serialport: Couldn't set term attributes");
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}
```

Comment: If you're using Linux, you might be able to use block devices/controls in /sys/class/gpoio/ to power on/off the device.  You may have to MUX/set the gpios/pins with a tool like devmem2 (used for TI OMAPs) or by patching the kernel or boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? I'll test it tomorrow.

```
int status;

status |= TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status);

usleep(500*1000);

status &= ~TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status);
```

Comment: This is pretty bad.  You are using an uninitialized integer (`status`) so your program will exhibit undefined behavior and could do anything.  You should use TIOCMGET to get the status first, then change the bit you are interested in, then use TIOCMSET.

Comment: Yes. I've learned a lot since asking this question. The code here is pretty cringe worthy... Although, I did preface it with "rough test code". Should I delete this question? It doesn't seem of much use to anybody.